# Symbol for the set of all timestamps?

Tags: time-series

Is there any convention to denote the set of all timestamps such as $\mathbb{T}$? By timestamp I mean date and time that could indicate events in an irregular time series. I am just asking because I want to use such a symbol in a formalization of a time series problem and do not want to invent something new if a convention already exists.

Comment: Welcome to stackexchange. Short answer: I don't think so. Why do you need such a symbol? If you [edit] the question to show us some context - perhaps several sentences in which you would use this - maybe we can help.